# Power Automate flow which generates a PDF file containing the SharePoint item barcode and the title, to be sent to a label printer

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, onedrive, power-automate

We need to implement the following :

1. Create a Power Automate flow which get called from a canvas app
2. The Power Automate flow will accept one parameter for the Item ID, generate a PDF file containing the SharePoint item barcode and under the barcode to show the item title. For this, I will use the OneDrive actions to generate the file and convert it to PDF.

[image]

But:

1. Can I get the barcode image generated by SharePoint and show it inside the generated file?
2. Can I control the generated file height and width? As the label printer that will be printing the barcode/title will accept labels with 102 mm x 152 mm dimension?

How do I implement this?

**Note:** I do not want to use the power app `PDF()` function to generate the PDF, as the items titles might contain none-Latin characters, which are not currently supported by the `PDF()` function inside Power Apps.